# Does Box plot with many outliers effects the result?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I am using Haberman's cancer survival dataset https://www.kaggle.com/gilsousa/habermans-survival-data-set
to draw a box plot. Here Surv_status is the target variable which has two classes and axil_nodes_det is the feature. I am getting the plot as follows with too many outliers from the first class

[image: Box plot for habrman's survival dataset]

I want to know whether more outliers will affect the prediction of output

Comment: Depends what models you are going to use and in what way. There is no way to tell beforehand.

Comment: Can a box plot have these many outliers?

Comment: Are those really "outliers"? Class 1 has >50% of its samples with a value of 0, while Class 2 has <25% of its values equal to 0. It's tough to tell, but the distributions don't really look all that different aside from that. Boxplots are a useful visualization tool, but I wouldn't rely on it for outlier detection - the tradeoff between longer whiskers and fewer outliers is rather arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments suggest, it's not always helpful to think of points outside the whiskers as "outliers". What you are seeing in these boxplots is a strong positive skew. And yes, a strongly skewed target is typically harder to predict than a less-skewed target.

In [traditional survival analysis](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~madigan/W2025/notes/survival.pdf), it's common to model this skewed data using a parametric probability distribution that naturally produces positive and positive-skewed data, e.g. the Weibull distribution.

Otherwise, you can also try a [Box-Cox](https://freakonometrics.hypotheses.org/14678) or [inverse hyperbolic sine (IHS)](http://worthwhile.typepad.com/worthwhile_canadian_initi/2011/07/a-rant-on-inverse-hyperbolic-sine-transformations.html) transformation on the survival time to reduce the skew.

For visualizing strongly-skewed data, you can either apply one of the above skew-reducing transformations, or use an ["adjusted" boxplot](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/An-adjusted-boxplot-for-skewed-distributions-Hubert-Vandervieren/2ab5f970edaa27260aedc216985a78f3de0478c8), which have an [R implementation](https://rdrr.io/cran/robustbase/man/adjbox.html).